# Landlord keep showing up unannounced. What can I do?

Tags: rental-property, landlord, harassment

I have a 12 month lease agreement with a property management company. The owner, NOT the property manager, keeps showing up, unannounced for dumb things, then gets upset when we don't let them in. This to me is harassment and needs to stop.

I spoke with the property manager and she is in agreement with me.

Another problem is that the owner's two sons, each live on the same property and come over to my side without my permission and unannounced too.

They interrupt my kids schooling, they interrupt my work, and they are making my life miserable.

Today the landlord had the courtesy to give a two hour notice. My wife said no. She hung up on my wife and was offended because she was told no. Her husband showed up shorty after, again, unannounced and angry.

What can I do? How much legal ground do I have to stand on? Can I file a small claims civil suit and it have merit?

Comment: Where do you live? (county, state, country, etc)

Comment: The answer to this varies hugely based on where you live.  Without knowing that, it's impossible to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

At common law, a tenant is entitled to "quiet enjoyment" of the property. This means that the owner can only interact with the tenant as spelled out in the lease or in an emergency situation.

First, calmly and quietly write down a list of your grievances. Then check your lease to see what the landlord is entitled to do. Cross off any grievances that are permitted by the lease.

Take this and the lease to your solicitor and pay him to write a letter to your agent advising them of your grievances and asking that they stop.

Without knowing where you are, we do not know what additional rights and dispute resolution procedures are available in your jurisdiction. Very few jurisdictions still rely entirely on common law as real estate is one of the most highly government regulated areas of life wherever you are. Your solicitor will know and, for less that a week's rent will give you solid advice.

Comment: Spot on--the answer is a letter from a landlord-tenant lawyer on a lawyer's letterhead.  One suggestion, though: do not "cross of any grievances that are permitted by the lease."  Use them for a separate list you give the lawyer, below those grievances, so he can determine whether they are permitted in your jurisdiction and decide whether to include them in the letter.

Comment: @Tom makes a good point. Leases often contain provisions that are void under local law, so things that the lease purports to allow the landlord to do may actually be forbidden. A lawyer will know about those.